# Dynamically add element to map after pattern matching

Tags: scala, maps, pattern-matching

I have a method as follows:

```
  protected def extract(implicit params:Params) =
    Map(
  "address" -> params.address,
  "city" -> params.address,
  "region" -> params.region,
)collect {
    case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
  }
```

I want to substitute value of city such that :

```
"city" -> if(params.city.contains("York")) "NewYork" else params.city,
```

How can I achieve this in scala?

Comment: Updated query on this(solution provided by Stephen worked btw)
How do I make this case insensitive i.e I need to handle both "York" and "york".
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in line

```
def extract(implicit params:Params) = 
    Map(
  "address" -> params.address,
  "city" -> (if(params.city.contains("York")) Some("NewYork") else params.city),
  "region" -> params.region
) collect {
    case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
  }
```

Im sure there are lots of other way to do it. Not sure what your really after.

Comment: With this solution , I am getting error like:"Cannot resolve symbol params"

Comment: sorry by bad. I've fixed that. It needed extra parenthises. Also its not clear whats an option and whats not,

Comment: this solution worked for me ,but now I have another problem.
I need to make the condition in if loop as case insensitive i.e.it should accept "York","york","YORK" etc.any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Stephens approach of just creating the map with the correct value is probably best.  If you've got a general map, of what appears to be String to Option[String], and want to substitute the city key if the value contains York, then this will work as well.

```
 myMap.collect {
    case ("city", Some(city)) if(city.contains("York")) => "NewYork"
    case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
  }
```

Comment: For this, I am getting error like :

    '=>' expected but string literal found.

Comment: ah yes, fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

Small correction to Bruce answer

```
myMap.collect {
   case ("city", Some(city)) if(city.contains("York")) => "NewYork"
   case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
}
```

Would not result in a Map, but an Iterable

```
myMap.collect {
   case ("city", Some(city)) if(city.contains("York")) => "city" -> "NewYork"
   case (k, Some(v)) => k -> v
}
```

Would be better